# iOS12, kReachabilityChangedNotification is not worked

Tags: ios, ios8, ios12

iOS 12 version is not work to kReachabilityChangedNotification.

(The networking change Notification. 
 NO accessibility technology)

but iOS 8 version is good working.

what happend?

Xcode version is 10.1

how to get fix?

Comment: Have you enabled "Access WiFi Information" in the "Capabilities" section of your App?

Comment: Yes i setting the "Access WiFi Information". but i think no relation that's option. Apple sample code too no working on iOS12... ha... what happen...

Comment: Not an answer, but you should consider adopting `NWPathMonitor` instead of reachability

Comment: Hi Paulw11. i used language to Object C. NWPathMonitor is support only Switft. thanks.

Comment: No, you can use path monitoring in Objective C - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/b728b5dfad8bc6f4c63e568c202bd7e5

Comment: ok! i will try now! really thanks!

Comment: Hi  Paulw11. I tested u r code. code is good work on Foreground. But no working on background. Reachability was working on Background and Foreground. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Reachability not Notification reason is,

USB cable connecting with XCode debug mode.

(But ios8 version device is no problem, only ios12 version device have a problem)
.
.
.
.
.

But correct operation to Notification, disconnect USB cable without XCode,

Answer (score -3):

In iOS 12 Reachability feature is off by default. You must manually enable it on your iPhone by venturing into Settings → General → Accessibility → Reachability.

For more information you can check this [link](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2018/06/12/ios-12-reachability-fix/)

You can also try adding NSAppTransportSecurity to info.plist file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
 <dict>  
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
 </dict>
```

Comment: The OP is asking about the network reachability framework, not the accessibility technology

Comment: This could be one of the reason that  network reachability  its working in iOS 8 and not in iOS 12.

Comment: No, because you are talking about the reachability feature where a double touch of the touchID sensor brings the top of the screen down.  The OP is asking about network reachability; an entirely different thing

Comment: HI pooja. thanks u r comment. But u a know how is all incorrect. My mean is same with Paulw11.